# Need to point my javascript or other script source to another website

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

Ultimatly what I want to do is look for, is the text ***It's just you!*** or ***It's not just you!*** within the container ID of: '**< div id="container">**' within the source of the resulting page of isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk.

I have found a way to do this now, but cannot point the Java to the correct site. What I have done is use the following URL: ***isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk***. However, I am having problems doing this. Can someone let me know of a way of either using Javascript or another script source that can be used, without hosting the webpage from webserver. So running the webpage from local client computer.

Here is my last attempt I have come up with and failed miserably so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Specify where the sctipt should be running the code against.
window.location.protocol = "http"
window.location.host = "isup.me/echelonservices.co.uk"

//Look for the Class ID and output to a variable.
element = document.getElementById('container');
var Status = element.textContent || element.innerText;

//If the "Status" says: UP write UP, DOWN write DOWN and anything else write Status could not be determined!
if (Status=="UP") {document.write('<div style="color:#00BB00;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">UP</div>')}
else {if (Status=="DOWN") {document.write('<div style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">DOWN</div>')}
else {document.write('<div style="color:#EDA200;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">WARNING:<br>Status could not be determined!</div>')};};
</script>
```

Comment: The last paragraph of coe works without a hitch. Its the first, and maybe the second, that I need assistance with.

Comment: you have to modify the response at that url to emit cors headers. if you can't, you can't use the data from javascript in a browser.

Comment: I don't think you can access a DOM from another domain with JavaScript.  You'll need to implement this with server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, what you're doing isn't possible.  JavaScript cannot read data from another domain (unless that domain is set up explicitly to allow it) - even if that domain is *localhost*.  Otherwise, it would be possible to create a web page that loads Facebook in a hidden IFrame and steals a bunch of confidential user data.

What you'll need to do instead is implement this same logic up on your own web server, using the server side programming language of your choice (PHP, Java, C#, etc).  You'd initiate an HTTP request to the desired server, parse the results accordingly, and then echo the results to the client.  Basically, you're creating a proxy to that service.

If you're trying to do this without using a web server *at all*, you might want to check into another client-side technology such as WPF, Air, WinForms, Java, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox, `element.innerText` isn't supported.  Use `element.innerHTML` instead.  Also, I'm not sure if this is a typo, but you have an extra closing bracket around your final `else` statement.  I would recommend using a different syntax for your `if` statements to make them neater:

```
if (Status=="UP") {
document.write('<div style="color:#00BB00;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">UP</div>')
}
else if (Status=="DOWN"){
document.write('<div style="color:#FF0000;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">DOWN</div>')
}
else {
document.write('<div style="color:#EDA200;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold">WARNING <br>Status could not be determined!</div>')
}
```

Comment: lol yeah thanks for that. I am a newby in Javaworld and just a little over-eager to code :D

Now implemented Thanks.